# Burned out High Voltage Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, over-voltage-protection

Have a high voltage CAP (C4) that was put into a *new* design.  Supposedly it was chosen with the *old* design parameters in mind.  But since its inception it continued burning out.  Should we attempt swapping it out for a higher Voltage rated CAP?  It should be noted that the new CAP (C4) is rated for 4 AMPS where as the old was 24 AMPS.

C4 is on the top rail after the inductor chain.

[image: Layout of circuit]

Comment: Well, is the current above 4 A?

Comment: Is your image of the new design or the old one? What are the differences between the two? Provide part #s or datasheets for old and new capacitors. There are other relevant parameters besides max Ripple Current.

Comment: @Frosty This is the drawing of what it should be.  The CAP is a: 27250B202Jo0 Richardson RFPD   It's rated to 5,000 VDC RMS I believe.  It varies in time how long it takes to fail.  It's always been the C4 CAP that fails.

Comment: @BrianCarlton from what we're reading the answer is no.  It's in the mA range still.

Comment: @Frosty It should be noted that this failure ONLY happens when they put their max Power output to 100% on the system.  (They have a variable input to create tiers).  They haven't had the failure anywhere else.

Comment: Still need more details. What was the original part#? what Frequency is this device running at? What is the max output power?

Comment: Also, you haven't indicated whether your included image is the "new" design or the old one and what differences there are between the two.

Comment: It seems strange to me that you have electrolytic capacitors in a high voltage, high frequency application.

Comment: @jre, those are not electolytics. They are drawn as polarized caps to show the orientation of the capacitor in-circuit so that the "outside foil" end is connected to the low-impedance side of the junction. Here is some further explanation: http://www.aikenamps.com/index.php/where-to-connect-the-outside-foil-on-capacitors

Comment: The part you reference is a nonpolarized mica capacitor, which for some reason is drawn as a polarized capacitor in your schematic.

Comment: @Frosty:  the linked site also clearly says that "outside foil" doesn't apply to mica or ceramic capacitors - and I'm having a hard time believing that there was a paper wound capacitor in a position where it has to pass several amperes.

Comment: Urk.  Just noticed.  " It should be noted that the new CAP (C4) is rated for 4 AMPS where as the old was 24 AMPS." Do you think maybe, just maybe, that has something to do with the problem?

Comment: So, is this an inductive heater?

Comment: @JRE Correct.  It heats up a coil ultimately.

Comment: I think your problem comes from the current rating, not the voltage rating.

Comment: @JRE We're going to try and swap the CAPs for CAPs on another system that they were trying to clone with this one.  They've never blown and have the higher current rating.  I'll let you guys know what I find.  We're open to any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors aren't usually rated in Amps, but there is a upper current limit due to dissipation with the internal ESR (equivalent series resistance).

First, replacing something rated for 24 A with something rated for 4 A without knowing anything else is a stupid thing to do.  Burning out the component, starting a fire, or vanishing into a greasy black mushroom cloud should all be expected outcomes.

Second, do the math.  What current will flow thru the cap at what frequency?  Your schematic doesn't show what kind of tube V1 is, nor the values of the plate resistors, so there is little more that anyone can help with here.  From those values, you could get a upper bound on the current thru the cap.

Since this is apparently a RF oscillator, you also have to check that the cap still acts like a cap at the intended frequency, which you also haven't stated.  No real capacitor is perfect, and all real capacitors have a upper frequency bound on their operation.  Electrolytic caps are especially poor at this.  The schematic shows the cap being polarized, so it is probably electrolytic.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. C4 in close-up.*

I am not familiar with valve amplifiers but it appears that the 3A is the HT supply for the valve anode. Therefore, I suspect that C4's polarity is incorrect.

Measure the voltage across it in circuit to check. Wear safety glasses.

Comment: HT here is ~2kV if I'm reading the diagram correctly. When dealing with those sorts of voltages I don't think "wear safety glasses" is a sufficient cautionary note. Also, I believe the polarity markings on those capacitors are to indicate which side should have the "outside foil end" attached to it. In RF circuits you always want the outside foil connected to the lower impedance side of the circuit since it acts as a sheild for the other leg of the capacitor.

Comment: So update on the issue.  Apparently the CAPs should be speced the same as the CAPs on the old system.  The new system is supposively an exact mirror of the old.  We found that is not the case.  The CAP keeps blowing up and will only last at a max of 2 hours.  We didn't assemble the system so we're wondering if building it from the ground up is a good option.  Feeling pretty stuck right now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'll be of any further help. I hope you can sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but not all micas are created equal.  Older micas were usually plain mica.  New ones, depending on size, may be mica composite, smaller mica pieces bonded with various polymers.